# Spock/Grails - Groovy:unable to resolve class grails.test.mixin.TestFor and unable to resolve class spock.lang.Specification

Tags: grails, spock

I am creating a Spock test for my plugin `project-plugin` and my main project name is `main-project` which is using `project-plugin` as a plugin. So when I am creating a Spock test for my plugin its throwing above error means its warning `project-plugin` has error because of below class.

Is creating Spock test for plugin will differ to creating Spock test for main project.

For example I have created a new sample project and created spock test for service which is working without any error.

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification
@TestFor(DataImportService){

}
```

I have also tried refreshing dependency with command `grails> refresh-dependencies -Dplugins.useInline=true` **Dependencies refreshed.** but still same error.

Should I run my unit test cases with `main-project` or `plugin-project`.

How to sort this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

add to gradle :

```
testCompile "org.grails:grails-test-mixins:3.3.0"
```

Source:
https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-test-mixin-plugin/latest/guide/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I've created numerous Spock tests (unit and integration) for inline-plugins in the applications I work on.  Basically the application is a shell and some number of inplace-plugins -- the applications themselves are dirt simple.

Organization is pretty straightforward. BuildConfig.groovy in each app picks the plugins that it is composed of using   grails.plugin.location.'plugin-name' = '../../plugins/plugin-name'

```
+- applications
|     |
|     +- app1
|     +- app2
|     +- app3
|
+- plugins
      |
      +- plugin1 
      +- plugin2 (there are > 30 plugins in total)
```

Nothing special about creating the tests, either manually, or through IntelliJ IDE. The tests all live in application > test > [integration | unit] folders (yeah, I should refactor in order to get code-coverage to work properly).
Works for Domain classes, Controllers, or Services. (Grails 2.4.3 / 2.4.5)

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import spock.lang.specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

@TestFor(SomeService)
@Mock([OtherService])
class SomeService extends Specification {
    def "some method"() {
        given:
            // setup
        when:
            // action
        then:
            // test outcomes
        cleanup:
            // undo any metaClassing, etc
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean to say there is no difference in writing Spock test for **project** or **plugins**

Comment: I am not getting point when i created a new sample project and wrote spock test which is working fine but my official existing project its giving `class resolution error`

Comment: What grails version, and what does your BuildConfig look like for the main project? Might be something there.

Comment: I am using 2.4.4 and its same as default with additional plugins required

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. My Spock unit tests were working until I tried rolling back an update for an unrelated plugin. I'm not sure how, but IntelliJ stopped recognizing any of my project's plugins.

Here is what I think fixed it:

- In explorer, backup and delete the folder `C:\\[my project root]\\work\\projects\\[project name]`
- In IntelliJ IDEA (15.0.4), `Build->Rebuild Project`
- Then `File->Close Project` and reopen the project.

That last step finally got it working. Here is everything else I tried in case that doesn't work by itself:

- `grails clean`
- `grails refresh-dependencies`
- Forced svn update to HEAD
- In IntelliJ, `File->Invalidate Caches / Restart...`